# How to remove a specific key from a JavaScript object and replace it with its value as a new property

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object with nested objects. every nested object has a key called "model" and its value. I want to remove the "model" key from every nested object and replace it with its value as a new property. This way, the resulting object will have the same values but without the "model" key.

here is the code :

```
let data = {
    car: {
        model: 1999
    },
    van: {
        model: 1850
    }
};
```

The desired output is:

```
let data = {
    car : 1999,
    van: 1850
}
```

after long search i find out the solution for it :

```
// Iterate over each key in the data object

for (let key in data) {
    // want to Check if the current key has a nested object with a "model" key
    
if (data[key].hasOwnProperty("model")) {

    // store the value of the "model" key
    let value = data[key].model;
    
    // remove the "model" key from the nested object
    delete data[key].model;
    
    // add a new property with the same key and the stored value
    data[key] = value;
}
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Would you like to try something like so: `const newData = { "car": data.car.model, "van": data.van.model };`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries)from the data object (key/value pairs in an array), and then iterate over them to update a new object.

```js
const data={car:{model:1999},van:{model:1850}};

// Initialise a new object
const out = {};

// Get the entries from the data
// Each entry will be an array  with
// a key/value pair:
// ["car", { "model": 1999 }]
const entries = Object.entries(data);

// Then for each of those arrays destructure
// the key and obj, and update your new object
// using that information
for (const [key, obj] of entries) {
  out[key] = obj.model;
}

// Ta da!
console.log(out);
```

Additional documentation

- [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = {
    "car": {
        "model": 1999
    },
    "van": {
        "model": 1850
    }
}

const dataFormated = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [k, {model}]) => ({...acc, [k] : model}), {})
```

Comment: Adding links to documentation for `Object.entries` and `reduce`, and adding some comments to your code would make your answer better.

Comment: it works but you forget to put k in the second one instead of key thank you so much

Comment: Yes mb, was on mobile phone

Answer (score 0):

You can do using this approach

```
let data = {
    "car": {
        "model": 1999
    },
    "van": {
        "model": 1850
    }
}

let result = Object.keys(data).map(function(e){
    return {[e] : data[e]['model']};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = {
  car: {
    model: 1999,
  },
  van: {
    model: 1850,
  },
};
let dataarray = Object.entries(data);
data = {};
for (let i = 0; i < dataarray.length; i++) {
  data[dataarray[i][0]] = dataarray[i][1].model;
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.